# Cloning and Adding Hyper-V VM to Domain

Tags: c#, powershell, clone, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have a standalone (not clustered, but in the domain) Windows Server 2016 with Hyper-V role installed.
I need to clone VMs on a daily basis, so I wrote a few small "things" using C# and PowerShell.

1. Parallel Copy of VHD

   ```cs
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
       var sourceFile = args[0];
       var distanationDir = args[1];
       int numOfCopies = Int32.Parse(args[2]);

       //var sourceFile = $@"C:\temp\123.VHD";
       //var distanationDir = $@"C:\temp\vhds\";
       //int numOfCopies = 15;

       StartJob(sourceFile, distanationDir, numOfCopies, random);
   }

   private static void StartJob(string sourcefile, string distanationdir, int numOfCopies, Random random) {
       int count = 0;
       Parallel.For(0, numOfCopies, i => {
           Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, thread = {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

           try {
               string atrib = Path.GetExtension(sourcefile);
               string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
               var copyNew = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourcefile) + guid + atrib;
               File.Copy(sourcefile, Path.Combine(distanationdir + '\\', copyNew));
               Console.WriteLine(@"Started{copyNew}");
           } catch (IOException copyError) {
               Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The second step is to create VMs with this PowerShell script that creates a VM with existing VHDX.

   ```bsh
   $from = 81
   $howmany = 30

   $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\Hyper-v" -Filter *.vhdx
   if ($files) { 
       Write-Host "variable is not null" 
       try {
           $vmIndex = $from
           for ($i = 0; $i -lt $howmany; $i++) {
               Write-Host "Start  "
               New-Vm -Name "AUT-TA$vmIndex" -Path "E:\Hyper-v\Virtual Machines" -MemoryStartupBytes 4294967296 -VHDPath $files[$i].FullName -SwitchName "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #4 - Virtual Switch"
               Write-Host "Vm created " + "AUT-TA$vmIndex"
               $vmIndex++
               Write-Host "End"
           }
           exit
       } catch {
           [System.Exception]"caught a system exception"
       }
   } else {
       Write-Host "No such files"
       exit
   }
   ```
3. Last I need join them to the domain but I need some script that will be running for each VM on this host and adding it to the domain.

Comment: Some think like this $domain = "myDomain"
$password = "myPassword!" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "$domain\myUserAccount" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential   .     BUT somethink that I can run ON a server hyper-v and that add  all VM's to domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a solution:**
run this commands on both client and server (before clone  or copy of VHD)

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="*"}'
```

After it run from hyper-v Host this (this only for add one VM , but you can create it ForEach ip of vm on host)

```
#Local Cred 
$passwordLoc = "Password" 
$usernameLoc = "localhost\Administrator"
$credentialsLoc = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($usernameLoc, (ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordLoc -AsPlainText -Force))
$ses = New-PSSession 192.168.90.91 -Credential $credentialsLoc 
##Domain Cred
$domain = "domain.com"
$password = "Password"
$username = "$domain\PowerUser"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force)) 
Invoke-command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {
Add-Computer -DomainName $using:domain -Credential $using:credentials  -ErrorAction Stop 
Rename-Computer -NewName "AUT-TA41" -DomainCredential $using:credentials -Force -ErrorAction Stop
Restart-Computer -ErrorAction Stop}
```

*And this Works!*

Answer (score 1):

Since you should be able to use PowerShell Direct, you can just get the VM's you want to execute on, then `Invoke-Command -VMName` the `Add-Computer` command. Your comment implies that you want to save the password in the script. Just remember the security implications of that.

```
$domain = "myDomain" 
$password = "myPassword!" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
$username = "$domain\myUserAccount" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$passwor‌​d) 
Get-VM | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Command -VMName $_.name -ScriptBlock {Add-Computer -DomainName $using:domain -Credential $using:credentia}}
```

Comment: Supply values for the following parameters:
An error has occurred which Windows PowerShell cannot handle. A remote session might have ended.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (AUT-TA100:String) [], PSRemotingDataStructureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken

This is what I receive and every time I need enter credentials

Comment: @AndreyDzhezhora, did you change `$domain`, `$password`, and `$username` to all reflect your domain values?  If so, it should work!

Comment: @FoxDeploy Yes definitely .

Comment: Maybe I need do some prerequisites on VMs? Run some Commands?